# C++ performance: string versus pointer in binary tree

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I built a template class to hold a binary tree, called tTree.
Another class has two instances of tTree to which it copies data when accepting a new node.

The first one is used for name lookups - it maps strings to a binary tree and associates each string to a Node pointer. This pointer is then used by various classes for directly approaching different nodes without having to look them up again. This part currently works very, very well.

The second one is used to store more details on a given node. It maps node pointers and associates them with a small struct, which is copied by value. This one works, but it much slower.

I have a stress test that adds one million nodes with randomly generated names, then verifies the tree's integrity.
For science, I ran four tests, each time storing different data in the tree. As you can see, the difference in completion times is quite amazing:

```
tTree<Node*,std::string>       // Completed in ~46 seconds
tTree<Node*, Node*>            // Completed in ~78 minutes
tTree<std::string,std::string> // Completed in ~44 seconds
tTree<std::string,Node*>       // Completed in 2 hours
```

In my implementation, the *second* argument is what's being searched on. I know, it's silly, I'll probably change it.

Within tTree, the comparison between search data is as simple as it could be:

```
if ( data < currentbranch->data ) { /* Copy to or dive into left branch */  }
if ( data > currentbranch->data ) { /* Copy to or dive into right branch */ }
```

I did notice that each add in a run takes around the same amount of time - I noticed no increasing delay between adding two nodes as the test continued - so I don't think that the increased tree size is slowing anything down.

I tested this on Windows 10 64bit using QT Creator 4.1.0 and MinGW 5.3.0. Nothing in the code used here uses STL or QT code.

Why are searches with pointer comparison so much slower?

Comment: Do you distinguish comparable types from pointers to comparable types? Or do you compare raw pointers?

Comment: Raw pointers. tTree directly compares T2 without trying to dereference. The class is then instantiated with Node* for T2.

Comment: Is it intentionally? It looks like using `char*` as key in `std::map` (which is obviously wrong).

Comment: No char*, and I'm not using std::map - tTree is a class I wrote, and I've only passed it Node* and std::string so far.